# 500 Error: '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: ios, json, flutter, dart, mapping

I've authentication feature in the iOS app (on flutter), here is the `User` class:

```
class User {
  final String fullname;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String token;
  final String type;
  final String id;
  final String pin;
  final bool isVerified;
  User({
    required this.fullname,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.token,
    required this.type,
    required this.id,
    required this.pin,
    required this.isVerified,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'fullname': fullname,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'token': token,
      'type': type,
      'id': id,
      'pin': pin,
      'isVerified': isVerified,
    };
  }

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      fullname: map['fullname'] ?? '',
      username: map['username'] ?? '',
      email: map['email'] ?? '',
      password: map['password'] ?? '',
      token: map['token'] ?? '',
      type: map['type'] ?? '',
      id: map['_id'] ?? '',
      pin: map['pin'] ?? '',
      isVerified: map['isVerified'] ?? false,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromJson(String source) => User.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

The problem starts on login page after checking credentials:

```
void sendOtp({
   required BuildContext context,
   required String email,
   required String sendPurpose,
   required VoidCallback onTapDialogButton,
 }) async {
   try {
     showDialogLoader(context);

     http.Response res = await http
         .post(Uri.parse("$uri/api/sendOtp/$sendPurpose"),
             headers: <String, String>{
               "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
             },
             body: jsonEncode({
               "email": email,
             }))
         .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 25));
     Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
     print(res.statusCode);
     statusCodeHandler(
       context: context,
       response: res,
       onSuccess: () {
         showAlertMessage(
           context: context,
           title: "Verify Account",
           message: "Please Check Mail For OTP Code",
           onTap: onTapDialogButton,
         );
       },
     );
   } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
     showTimeOutError(
       context: context,
       popDialogAndLoader: true,
     );
   } on SocketException catch (e) {
     showNoInternetError(
       context: context,
       popDialogAndLoader: true,
     );
   } on Error catch (e) {
     print('Send Otp Error: $e');
   }
 }
```

the error on the Console says `Send Otp Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'` and the main page that should appear after authentication doesn't open

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue in your `User.fromJson` method fix this as:

from:

```
factory User.fromJson(String source) => User.fromMap(json.decode(source));
```

to:

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User.fromMap(json);
```

Change the Parameter type to User

```
void setUser(User user) {
  _user = user;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: I've got an error in other class then where the user set as a String `void setUser(String user) {
    _user = User.fromJson(user);
    notifyListeners();
  }`, maybe the problem is on login screen cuz `username: usernameController.text`? I guess I need to convert user to string

Comment: Please paste the code of your other class where you're setting the user and getting error.

Comment: `class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User _user = User(
    fullname: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    token: '',
    type: '',
    id: '',
    pin: '',
    isVerified: false,
  );

  //creating getter for user
  User get user => _user;

  void setUser(String user) {
    //data fromjson coming from models/user.dart
    _user = User.fromJson(user);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}`

Comment: still got an issue on line `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser(res.body);` it says `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'` how can I convert res.body to string?

Comment: Update above code as: `Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser(User.fromJson(res.body));`

Comment: First error did back, I've messaged you in the chat